# Create/Call a Function so I don't have to insert the same code several times?

Tags: php

**some background :** My webste integrates a File Manager (FileGator) that allows users to consult the files present in it, and also functionnalities like upload/move/create or delete files. The code I'm working on determines the privileges of the current user and only displays the functionnalities if he has the rights privileges.

When a user registers on the website, a repertory `$userdir` is created in which the member is granted functionnalities privileges. The code that allows me to display a functionnality for the user checks if one of thoses conditions is met :

- User has full rights
- User has normal rights but is on his main repertory `( /user/$userdir )`
- User has normal rights but is on one of the subfolders of his main repertory `( /user/$userdir/subfolder1 )`

So currently I have to repeat the full code for every functionnality (about eight).

Here is my code, with the upload functionnality :

```
<?php
    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
    $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
    $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory

    function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
        $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        foreach($folders as $folder){
            if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r')) || (gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))): ?>
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="fileinput-button nice radius button">
                <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>

                <span class=""><?php echo lang::get("Add Files...")?></span>

                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                <input type="hidden" name="uniqid" value="50338402749c1">
                </span>
<?php break; endif;
    scanDirectory($folder, $directory);
        }
    }

    scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);
?>
```

The only part of this code that changes is the HTML code inside the If condition, in my exemple this was the HTML to display the Upload functionnality. The code works fine but currently the same code is repeated for every functionnality in the page, while only the HTML part of the code is changing.

I'm still new in php and I was wondering if there is a way to simplify this, make the code less redundant.

Is there a way to transorm this into some kind of function ? Like write the full code once in a function.php file and then call it on my main page where i would only add he code of the functionnality.

Hope this is clear enough since I'm too sure if that is possible.

Thanks !

Comment: Might be a better fit for CodeReview? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I will post there if i have the confirmation that there is no possible way to include this only once in my page

Comment: Is it exactly the same code 8 times, or are there variable parameters? Either way, you definitely can and should make it DRY

Comment: Wasn't an answer but a comment... yes it is possible to include a function once only in the global scope - but there are potentially going to be a *lot* of ways to solve this and refactor your code; which makes it too broad for SO I feel.

Comment: Hello, Yes it is the exact same code exept for the HTML code that you can see inside the If function. Can i ask what DRY is ?

Comment: It's an acronym that simply means "Don't Repeat Yourself" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: Ok, I'm on mobile right now, if it isn't answered when I'm at home I will... For starters, make yourself aware what the differences are, everything that is the same should be static in your function while the variable parts should be parameters for the function. I think you should provide more details to get the best possible answer.

Comment: Allright thanks, i will edit my post to be as specific as possible

Comment: Start by separating the presention layer (HTML) from the logic used to determine is something is to be displayed. For example, instead of outputting HTML directly from the function, perhaps you set some flags like `$has_upload_privilege = true;` and then when you are going to display, you just check those flags to determine whether the corresponding HTML control should be shown.

Comment: That sounds like a very possible solution, this would work for every of the functionnalities with a general variable `$has_privileges` . Thanks for your answer.